# Paypal hosted iFrame Error: "Error Processing Payment.This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with another card."

Tags: php, iframe, paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a paypal business account and I'm using standard Payment in my webpage.

I want to integrate the hosted page product named "Plataforma Integral" in my Spanish website, using an iframe. I show properly the iframe and redirect to the specified sandbox url, but when I arrive at the sandbox platform (and event in the production platform), it shows the following generic error:

**Error Processing Payment
This transaction can't be processed. Please pay with another card.**

I have a sandbox paypal account and this is the data I'm sending:

```
<form method="get" id="formNewPaypal" name="formNewPaypal" action="https://securepayments.sandbox.paypal.com/webapps/HostedSoleSolutionApp/webflow/sparta/hostedSoleSolutionProcess">
       <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_hosted-payment">
        <input type="hidden" name="business" value="[SANDBOX_USER_ID]"> 
        <input type="hidden" name="subtotal" value="50">
        <input type="hidden" name="paymentaction" value="sale">
        <input type="hidden" name="return" value="[RETURN_URL]">
        <input type="hidden" name="cancel_return" value="[CANCEL_URL]">
        <input type="hidden" name="template" value="templateD">
    <input style="display:none;" type="submit" value="Pay Now" id="submit" name="submit"> 
</form>
```

I've tried sending by POST and GET methods, and without params, and the error is always the same.

Could you tell me what's wrong or what I'm missing to send or implement? Any help will be appreciated.

For further information, please don't hesitate to ask me.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Look at the paypal API documentation

Comment: Have you tried also supplying currency_code and billing_* fields? I am using POST method, and I open the form in an iframe by setting target attribute of the <form> tag to the iframe name, but I doubt that could be the reason.

Comment: Oh, and also - please look into your Sandbox account and ensure you have Hosted Payments (Plataforma Integral) enabled. It might also be that something is not completely set up with the Sandbox account.

Answer (score 2):

Solved! The problem was that my sandbox account was Business and must be upgraded to Business Pro.

Now I can reach the form, but when I click the Paypal Button, It access to paypal in the main window and not in the iframe. I'll keep searching.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: this thing didn't work for me.. i've turn all stones possible.. !!! anybody else could resolve this issue?

Comment: @MFarooqi PayPal Integral Evolution is not supported in United States. Maybe you need to create a Business Pro account with France as a country.